# updating second to last record in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have 3 primary keys. CompanyName, EmpNo, StartDate.

I want to create a stored procedure that can allow me to update only the second to last record of each empno. How can I achieve that? In this case I have to records per empnno but I want to update only the second to last record regardless of the amount of record
ex; If I have 100 records I want to update the 99th record of the same empno.

```
CompanyNo EmpNo    StartDate   FinalDate 
1           1     1999/01/01   2013/04/26   
1           1     2013/04/17   9999/12/31
1           2     1999/01/0    2013/04/26
1           2     2013/04/17   9999/12/31
1           3     1999/01/01   2013/04/26 
1           3     2013/04/17   9999/12/31
```

In this case I want to edit only the second to last in FinalDate.
these ones;

```
CompanyNo EmpNo    StartDate    FinalDate   
1           1      1999/01/01   2013/04/26  <--- this finaldate field
1           2      1999/01/01   2013/04/26  <--- this finaldate field
1           3      1999/01/01   2013/04/26  <--- this finaldate field
```

Comment: How does your primary key express the order of the records?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "edit the row"? Do you want to prevent updates on the other? What exactly do you want to update in that row?

Comment: I tried ordering my 3 primary keys by ASC and then tried using ROW_NUMBER but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about what you want, you can get the second finalfate for each empno / company by this

```
SELECT empNo FROM 
   (
   SELECT companyName, empNo, rank() over (PARTITION BY companyName,empNo
   ORDER BY FinalDate DESC) as rankings FROM yourTable
       ) WHERE ranking = 2
```

And you can do whatever update you need by

```
  Update yourTable set something = something WHERE empNo IN (  thatQueryAbove)
```

Comment: I edited my question. Apologies. Maybe needed to be more explicit. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for partitioning on multiple columns, is it necessary to enclose each column name in brackets?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, I'm pretty sure it's parentheses though. Maybe brackets work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a stored procedure for this. What you describe can be done with a single statement:

```
merge into employment emp
using
(
   select CompanyName, 
          empno, 
          startdate, 
          finaldate, 
          row_number() over (partition by CompanyName, EmpNo order by StartDate desc) as rnk
   from employment
) t on (t.companyname = emp.companyname and t.empno = emp.empno and t.startdate = emp.startdate and t.rnk = 2)
when matched then update
     set finaldate = date '2013-04-28';
```

This will change the `finaldate` for those rows to `'2013-04-28'`

Although I have to admit I don't understand what you are *really* trying to do.

Comment: I want to edit the second to last record of each employee. I will try to your code later today.

Comment: @Edu: the term "edit" does not make any sense with SQL. You update, delete or insert rows. You don't "edit" them.

Comment: I mistook when commenting on your code but I  used the term update in the title. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

Oracle provides a pseudo-column called [ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) in queries. So if you know the total size of your dataset (count it), you can access to the second to last row using ROWNUM, get the primary key values and update it properly.